# Exception: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum when comparing two Strings

Tags: ruby

Simple Ruby question but it's driving me crazy. I have a method to compare two strings and return 1 if string one includes string two. The method is in a Module.

This is the code:

```
  def self.check_similarity first_string, second_string
    first_string.gsub!(/\s+/, "")
    first_string.downcase!
    second_string.gsub!(/\s+/, "")
    second_string.downcase!
    if first_string.include? second_string
      return 1
    end
  end
```

While debugging, when I get to the `if` line, I get `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum comparing two Strings`. I debugged and printed the string's classes and they're never nil or anything different from String. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I ran unit tests on the method and it works as expected. The problem must be coming from somewhere else, so I'll keep on checking the code out.

Comment: That works perfectly, the only problem I see is that the method will: return nil unless first_string.include? second_string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if gsub! does no substitutions, then it returns nil. see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-gsub-21)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > first_string = "nospaces"
 => "nospaces" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > first_string.gsub!(/\s+/, "")
 => nil
```

be sure not to use nil in your if clause

Comment: But since I'm not assigning first_string to anything, then it should be no problem, right?
~$ irb
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > first_string = "hola"
     => "hola" 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > first_string.gsub!(/\s/,"")
     => nil 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > puts first_string
    hola
     => nil 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 >

Comment: tried your method and it worked for me. I think there is a problem outside this method. are you sure that first_string and second_string are never nil?

Comment: I'm accepting the answer since the code does work, so the question is sort of invalid. After doing some nil checks and adding unit tests, everything is working fine.